# Create a parse-able string from a named list and function name

Tags: r

I have apparently a simple one that my grey matter currently refuses to grasp - say I have a list:

```
list(a = "foo", b = c("bar", "biz", "booze"))
```

and a function `fn`. How can I get a string like this:

```
"fn(a = \"foo\", b = c(\"bar\", \"biz\", \"booze\"))"
```

P.S.

I know I'll regret for asking this one in the morning...

Comment: maybe a solution starting from `dput`?

Comment: Don't want to sound like `M-x doctor`, but @BenBolker could you elaborate on that one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also manipulate the language objects directly, as described in [Chapter 6](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Computing-on-the-language) of the R Language Definition:

```
X <- quote(list(a = "foo", b = c("bar", "biz", "booze")))
X[[1]] <- quote(fn)  ## as.symbol("fn") would also work
deparse(X)
# [1] "fn(a = \"foo\", b = c(\"bar\", \"biz\", \"booze\"))"
```

Or, if your list is already stored in a named object, you can just use `c()` and `as.call()` to piece together the desired call:

```
ll <- list(a = "foo", b = c("bar", "biz", "booze"))
deparse(as.call(c(as.symbol("fn"), ll)))
# [1] "fn(a = \"foo\", b = c(\"bar\", \"biz\", \"booze\"))"
```

Comment: Damn, this is even nicer idiom... and this is actually what I wanted to do, to change the `call` object itself, and not apply the ugly hack. Sorry @joran, this is just more elegant.

Comment: @aL3xa No problem! To the victor go the spoils...I will take comfort in the fact that my original attempt was trying to shoe horn `quote` into things, so clearly my subconscious was onto something...

Answer (score 5):

This should get you started, right...?

```
deparse(list(a = "foo", b = c("bar", "biz", "booze")),control = NULL)
[1] "list(a = \"foo\", b = c(\"bar\", \"biz\", \"booze\"))"
```

A more complete version, which I finished just as @aL3xa commented...

```
gsub("^list","fn",
    deparse(list(a = "foo", b = c("bar", "biz", "booze")),control = NULL))
```

Comment: I'll give you a check-mark, but I swear that this very moment I came up with: `deparse(list(a = "foo", b = c("bar", "biz", "booze")), control = "useSource")`, did `gsub` and voila...

Comment: In reply to your `gsub` edit, wouldn't it be easier just to `gsub('^list', 'fn', <the stupid list>)`?

Comment: @aL3xa Yes. I don't know why I got it in my head that I needed to do that. I guess I just like making things complicated.

Comment: Nah, you just don't treat regular expressions as panacea, unlike me. Which is good. The non-treating-them part... =)

Comment: If you pass just `"list"`, there's a chance that you'll replace stuff you don't want inside the string. Damn, I'm suffering from regex OCD! O_o

Comment: You can avoid the gsub like so: `deparse(call("fn", a = "foo", b = c("bar", "biz", "booze")))`